# Reducing Variance in Estimating the Exponential Average of Random Variables

Tags: data-transformation, expected-value, logarithm

Imagine we have a random variable called X, and the function form of the probability density for X is unknown. Now, I'm interested in finding the average value of the exponential of X, denoted as E[exp(X)]. The simplest way to do this is by taking N random samples, let's call them X_1, X_2, up to X_N, and then finding the average of their exponential values: (exp(X_1) + exp(X_2) + ... + exp(X_N)) / N.

However, there's an issue with this method. In most cases, a small portion of these samples will dominate the summation, causing the result to have a large variance.

Is there a different method we can use to estimate the average of exp(X) that doesn't suffer as much from this variance problem?

Comment: You may be interested in "importance sampling." Here is a link discussing the general idea: https://towardsdatascience.com/importance-sampling-introduction-e76b2c32e744 The method works when you already know the probability density or mass function for $X$, and you can generate samples using a modified density or mass function.

Comment: You really need to know something about the distribution.  For example, if $X$ has an exponential distribution with a mean of $\mu \ge 1$  and variance of $\mu^2$ then $\mathbb E[e^X]$ is infinite.

Comment: @Michael Unfortunately I don't know the probability density function for $X$.

Answer (score 4):

This is effectively the same as asking: *How can we estimate an average?* The exponential is just a re-expression of the variable with different numbers.

**Examples where either $X$ or $e^X$ might be observed**

Consider:

- Did you observe the [Richter magnitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richter_magnitude_scale) of earthquakes ($X$), or did you actually observe the amplitudes of the waves in the earth ($e^X$), and calculate the magnitudes as their logarithms?
- Did you observe the [absolute magnitudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_magnitude) of stars ($X$), or did you actually observe the radiant fluxes ($e^X$) and calculate the magnitudes as their logarithms?

So whether you observed the variable of interest $X$ or its exponential $e^X$ may not be clearly distinguished.

**General Techniques for Estimating Averages**

There are some general techniques for estimating the average of a variable $X$:

- You can take the mean of $X_1, \dots, X_n$.
- You can use importance sampling, as suggested in the comments, if you can oversample high $X$'s and weight them appropriately.
- If your $X$'s are paired with some associated variable $Y$, and you can weight them appropriately, you might oversample the $X$'s associated with particular values of $Y$. E.g.:

  - If $X$ = attendance at city parks, and $Y$ = day of week, you might more accurately estimate the average daily attendance by making more observations on the weekends.
  - If $X$ = income, and $Y$ = neighborhood, you might more accurately estimate average income by making more observations in richer neighborhoods.
- If you assume that $X$ is lognormally distributed, you might take the average $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ of $\log X$, and then estimate the average $X$ as $\exp(\mu+\sigma^2/2)$. This is a consistent, probably biased estimator for the mean of $X$, with a variance smaller than the direct estimate averaging the observations, especially beneficial for $\sigma>1$. Or perhaps you can do something similar with another transformation.

Perhaps you have a situation where one of these ideas will work and you can do better than taking the mean of the observations -- but in the absence of further detail on your issue, I wouldn't expect any luck of that sort.

**Appendix: Worked Example with Lognormals**

For the lognormal example, I use the R code below to calculate that with $\sigma=0.5$, the estimate via logs has a variance about $99$% of that from the direct estimate, but with $\sigma=2.0$, the estimate via logs has a variance about $20$% of that from the direct estimate.

```
directs = 1:10000
indirects = 1:10000

for (sigma in c(0.5,2)){
  for(i in 1:10000){
    x = rlnorm(10000, 0, sigma)
    y = log(x)
    directs[i]   = mean(x)
    indirects[i] = exp(mean(y) + sd(y)^2/2)
  }
  print(sprintf("for sigma = %3.1f:", sigma))
  print(sprintf(
    paste("variance by indirect method = %0.3f",
          "* variance by direct method"),
          var(indirects)/var(directs)))
  print(sprintf(
      paste("error by indirect method = %0.3f",
            "* error by direct method"),
      (mean(indirects)-exp(sigma^2/2))/
        (mean(directs)-exp(sigma^2/2))))   
}
```

Comment: +1. But I have to object -- this is not nit-picking -- that exponentiation is not what most people mean by "change of scale," which is usually understood as a constant multiplication of all values.  A convenient term, adopted by Tukey and others c. 1970, is "re-expression."  That refers to any monotonic (usually increasing) invertible function of the values.

Comment: I suspect @whuber is alluding to Tukey's [*Exploring Data Analysis*](https://archive.org/details/exploratorydataa00tuke_0), although it is possible Tukey mentioned it earlier.

Comment: @Galen That would be *Exploratory* Data Analysis (EDA), published in 1977 from notes of an earlier Princeton course.  The earliest reference I can find in Tukey's Collected Works is from an American Statistician article published in 1980.  The term "re-expression" in pervasive in Understanding Robust and Exploratory Data Analysis, 1983, with chapters contributed by a dozen authors.